# Click event of the recycler working only after scrolling

Tags: android, kotlin

I have viewpager on that two fragments,
the same adapter is attached to both the fragments. The click listener is getting attached only after scrolling the recycler view items.
Here is my code:
`
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
val binding = ItemChargingHistoryListBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), parent, false)
return ViewHolder(binding)
}

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val data = historyList[position]

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
        listener.onItemClickListener(position)
    }
    holder.binding.apply {
        if (data.sessionStatus == Constants.COMPLETED) {
            tvDownload.setOnClickListener {
                listener.onClickInvoiceButton(position)
            }

            imgFavorite.setOnClickListener {
                listener.onFavouriteClickListener(position = position)
            }
        }
        tvTitle.text = data.name
        imgFavorite.visibility= VISIBLE
            if (data.isFavourite == true){
                imgFavorite.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_red)
            }
            else{
                imgFavorite.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_stroke)
            }
            if (!data.time.isNullOrEmpty()){
                tvTime.visibility = VISIBLE
                imgTimer.visibility = VISIBLE
                tvTime.text = data.time.toString().split(":").first()+"h : "+data.time.toString().split(":").last()+"m"
            }else{
                tvTime.visibility = GONE
                imgTimer.visibility = GONE
            }
            if (!data.unitsCharged.isNullOrEmpty()){
                tvPower.visibility = VISIBLE
                imgPower.visibility = VISIBLE
                tvPower.text = data.unitsCharged+"/kWh"
            }else{
                tvPower.visibility = GONE
                imgPower.visibility = GONE
            }
            if (!data.connector.isNullOrEmpty()){
                tvType.visibility = VISIBLE
                imgType.visibility = VISIBLE
                tvType.text = data.connector
            }else{
                tvType.visibility = GONE
                imgType.visibility = GONE
            }
            if (!data.date.isNullOrEmpty()){
                tvDate.visibility = VISIBLE
                val dateFormatted=AppUtils.INSTANCE?.convertDateFormat(
                    dateFormatToRead = "yyyy-MM-dd",
                    dateFormatToConvert = "dd-MM-yyyy",
                    dateToRead = data.date?:""
                )
                tvDate.text =
                    context.getString(R.string.check_in_date) + " : " + (if (!dateFormatted.isNullOrEmpty()) " ${dateFormatted}" else "")
            }else{
                tvDate.visibility = GONE
            }
            if (!data.amount.isNullOrEmpty()){
                tvPriceKw.visibility = VISIBLE
                tvPriceKw.text = "₹"+data.amount
            }else{
                tvPriceKw.visibility = GONE
            }
        if (data.sessionStatus==Constants.FAILED){
            tvFailureReason.visibility= VISIBLE
                tvFailureReason.text=AppUtils.INSTANCE?.getFormattedString(stringOne = context.getString(R.string.failure_reason), stringTwo = data.failureReason)
                tvFeedback.visibility= VISIBLE
                tvFeedback.text=AppUtils.INSTANCE?.getFormattedString(stringOne = context.getString(R.string.feedback), stringTwo = data.feedback)
                imgFavorite.visibility= GONE
                layoutInfo.visibility= GONE
                tvPriceKw.visibility= GONE

        }`
```

I tried request focus, nested scrolling, smooth scrolling

Answer (score 0):

The codes you've provided seem difficult to interpret, but it appears that the click function of itemview might be overlapping the click function of tvDownload. Therefore, it may not be clickable.

Answer (score 0):

Move this code out side of apply (`holder.binding.apply` ) or write else case for this  `if (data.sessionStatus == Constants.COMPLETED)` put click listener code inside.

```
        tvDownload.setOnClickListener {
            listener.onClickInvoiceButton(position)
        }

        imgFavorite.setOnClickListener {
            listener.onFavouriteClickListener(position = position)
        }
```